# Selecting CheckBoxList From SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, checkboxlist

I have a scenario of a user and departments, user had to select and save his departs at time of registration,

and then on update it maybe edit by him, so, the problem is that on the update page, I want to set checked = true on list of user departs, which is populating from the user_info db

(=> checked = true on those only which was selected by user previously at the time of registration)

maybe its clear question, but if any confusion, I will clear it,

Thanks for Helping me...

Comment: Post code that you already tried. And let people know where exactly you are facing the issue.

Comment: I have a checkbox list from which i can select many checkboxes and save them. while coming to the same record i can see the checkboxed checked which i had saved earlier. Heres the code below.

Comment: string chkllist = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["test"].ToString();  string[] arr = chkllist.Split(','); chkllist = ",";
 foreach (string str in arr)
{ for (int j = 0; j < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; j++)
{ if (CheckBoxList1.Items[j].Text.Trim() == str.Trim())
{ CheckBoxList1.Items[j].Selected = true;                              break;}} if (str.ToString().Trim().ToLower().IndexOf("other") > -1)
{ other = str.Split(':');     chkOther.Checked = true;
                        if (other.Length > 1)
                            txtOther.Text = other[1];
                    }
                }

Comment: From where are you getting this `u.email = '" + Email +` value ?? Is it available during the page load ?? This is the only missing piece i can think of right now by looking at your code .

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution but again the problem is that,I am calling that function on pageLoad but it will not work on load, but when I refresh my page it will work fine, (I am Checking Through Item Value, because, I was saved that in database, instead of depart Name)

```
try
    {
        sqlcon.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select d.id from _dept d left join user u on u.id = d.id where u.email = '" + Email + "' order by d.id;", sqlcon);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ListItem li = ChkStatus.Items.FindByValue(reader["id"].ToString());
            if (li != null)
            {
                li.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Found Error in Selecting your depart!");
        Response.Redirect("user.aspx", false);
    }
    finally { sqlcon.Close(); }
```

Comment: Why that function will not work in `Page_Load` ?? Can you post your full code !

Comment: From where are you getting this `u.email = '" + Email +` value ?? Is it available during the page load ?? This is the only missing piece i can think of right now by looking at your code .